# Why does onLoad not fire on <script> when using Next.js's <Head>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) in order to load a third-party script. In order to know when the script has loaded, I added an `onLoad` handler to the `<script>` element but it never fires, even when the script has successfully loaded. Why?

Example:

```js
const ScriptComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <script
        src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"
        onLoad={() => console.log("script loaded")}
      ></script>
    </Head>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid, inline code like that has to be wrapped in quotes, not curly braces. Your syntax is React/JSX, but I assume what you have there gets inserted as-is, so you can't use that. You need `onload="console.log('script loaded')"`

Comment: That was entirely unexpected given that for everything else in JSX, [functions are passed in as handlers rather than strings](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), but you were right! Seems like this is a special quirk with `next/head`.

Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?